# How do I get values of another cell if a checkbox is selected of the corresponding checkbox in jtable?

Tags: java, swing, jtable

How do I get values of other cells if a checkbox is selected of the corresponding JCheckBox in JTable. I add JCheckbox in JTable:

```
JCheckBox checkBox = new javax.swing.JCheckBox();
jTable1 = new javax.swing.JTable();

jTable1.setModel(new javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel(
    new Object [][] {    
    },
    new String [] {
        "Station", "OperationName", "TliScantime", "StartTime", "Completedtime",
        "TliScanTime-StartTime", "StartTime-CompletedTime", "Select"
    }
) {
    Class[] types = new Class [] {
        java.lang.String.class, java.lang.String.class, java.lang.String.class,
        java.lang.String.class, java.lang.String.class, java.lang.String.class,
        java.lang.String.class, java.lang.Boolean.class
    };

    public Class getColumnClass(int columnIndex) {
        return types [columnIndex];
    }
});
jTable1.getColumn("Select").setCellEditor(new DefaultCellEditor(checkBox));
jTable1.setAutoResizeMode(javax.swing.JTable.AUTO_RESIZE_OFF);
jTable1.getColumnModel().getColumn(0).setPreferredWidth(120);
jTable1.getColumnModel().getColumn(1).setPreferredWidth(100);
jTable1.getColumnModel().getColumn(2).setPreferredWidth(80);
jTable1.getColumnModel().getColumn(3).setPreferredWidth(100);
jTable1.getColumnModel().getColumn(4).setPreferredWidth(100);
jTable1.getColumnModel().getColumn(5).setPreferredWidth(180);
jTable1.getColumnModel().getColumn(6).setPreferredWidth(180);

jScrollPane1.setViewportView(jTable1);
```

Now I want to do that when some one click on the JCheckbox, it will took the value from `TliScanTime-StartTime`, `StartTime-CompletedTime` colum of the selected rows means when JCheckbox is checked.

And it will show the average time of `TliScanTime-StartTime`, `StartTime-CompletedTime` in the two separated JLables. And value will be changed dynamically, meaning the average time is changed on every click on the checkbox. I add a checkbox on every rows is created.

What would be some help with some coding example be?

Comment: By "selected rows," do you mean "all rows having the checkbox selected" or "all rows in a `MULTIPLE_INTERVAL_SELECTION` selection model?"

Comment: please don't show code that's unrelated to the problem (f.i. column sizing has nothing to do with it)

Answer (score 1):

You may be able to adapt the approach shown [here](http://sites.google.com/site/drjohnbmatthews/table).

Comment: It is done by cell rendering am i right can i do this using any event handling.I want to try this using jTable1.getSelectionModel().addListSelectionListener(new javax.swing.event.ListSelectionListener() {
                        public void valueChanged(ListSelectionEvent event ) {
                       // if(jTable1.getValueAt(0,7).equals(null)){
                           Object b=jTable1.getValueAt(0,7);
                          
                           System.out.println(b); 
                       //}    
                        
                    }
                });

Comment: No, a `CellEditor` is required effect a change in the model, and the default editor does not have the behavior you require. Please edit your question to show code, which is hard to read in a comment.

Answer (score 1):

For [JTable](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html), you have to implement [TableModelListener](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/event/TableModelListener.html).

For example,

```
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.event.*;
import javax.swing.table.*;

public class TableCheckboxListenerExample {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            JFrame frame = new JFrame();
            frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JDialog.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
            DefaultTableModel model = new DefaultTableModel(new Object[][] {
                        {Boolean.FALSE, "Row 1"},
                        {Boolean.TRUE, "Row 2"}},
                    new String[]{"col1", "col2"}) {

                private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

                @Override
                public Class<?> getColumnClass(int columnIndex) {
                    if (getRowCount() > 0 && getValueAt(0, columnIndex) != null) {
                        return getValueAt(0, columnIndex).getClass();
                    }
                    return super.getColumnClass(columnIndex);
                }
            };
            model.addTableModelListener(new TableModelListener() {

                @Override
                public void tableChanged(TableModelEvent e) {
                    int row = e.getFirstRow();
                    int column = e.getColumn();
                    TableModel model = (TableModel) e.getSource();
                    Object data = model.getValueAt(row, column);
                    if (data instanceof Boolean) {
                        System.out.println("Value changed in Row: " + row + " Column: " + column + " New Value = " + data);
                    }
                }
            });
            JTable table = new JTable(model);
            frame.add(new JScrollPane(table));
            frame.pack();
            frame.setVisible(true);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private TableCheckboxListenerExample() {
    }
}
```