# Use a JCheckBox as DefaultCellEditor for my JTable's cells

Tags: java, swing, jtable

I am using this function to create a `jTable`, where some special **cells** have a `jComboBox` as editor :

```
void fillTable_(){
        final JComboBox myEditor = new JComboBox(new String[] {"yes", "no", "maybe"});
        String[][] data = new String[10][2];
            data[0][0] = "0,0";
            data[0][1] = "0,1";
            data[1][0] = "1,0";
            data[1][1] = "1,1";
            data[2][0] = "2,0";
            data[2][1] = "2,1";
            String[] columnNames = {"Nom", "Valeur"};
            DefaultTableModel model = new DefaultTableModel(data, columnNames);
            jTable1 = new JTable(model){
                DefaultCellEditor myCellEditor = new DefaultCellEditor(myEditor);
                @Override
                public TableCellEditor getCellEditor(int row, int column){
                    int modelColumn = convertColumnIndexToModel(column);
                    int modelRow = convertRowIndexToModel(row);
                    if(modelColumn == 1 && modelRow == 1){
                        return myCellEditor;
                    } else {
                        return super.getCellEditor(row, column);
                    }
                }
            };
    }
```

But the jTable stays empty *not even plain text display*. Is there something wrong?

Comment: and there are no `Exceptions` caught, too.

Comment: `jTable` v. `jTable1` could be a GUI editor problem.

Answer (score 3):

> But the `JTable` stays empty; not even plain text is displayed.

You need a renderer that corresponds to your editor, as suggested in this [example](http://sites.google.com/site/drjohnbmatthews/table) that contains both a `ValueRenderer` *and* a `ValueEditor`.

> I just need to put a `JComboBox` in some cells of the `JTable`:

As discussed in [*How to Use Tables: Concepts: Editors and Renderers*](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html#editrender), "a single *cell renderer* is generally used to draw all of the cells that contain the same type of data."

> I specified both row and column, but nothing is happening

Your code appears to work when I add the new `JTable` to a container.

[image: TableTest]

```
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import javax.swing.DefaultCellEditor;
import javax.swing.JComboBox;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTable;
import javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel;
import javax.swing.table.TableCellEditor;

/** @see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7200500 */
public class TableTest extends JPanel {

    public TableTest() {
        this.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(320, 240));
        final JComboBox myEditor = new JComboBox(
            new String[]{"yes", "no", "maybe"});
        String[][] data = new String[10][4];
        data[0][0] = "0,0";
        data[0][5] = "0,1";
        data[1][0] = "1,0";
        data[1][6] = "1,1";
        data[2][0] = "2,0";
        data[2][7] = "2,1";
        String[] columnNames = {"Nom", "Valeur"};
        DefaultTableModel model = new DefaultTableModel(data, columnNames);
        JTable table = new JTable(model) {

            DefaultCellEditor myCellEditor = new DefaultCellEditor(myEditor);

            @Override
            public TableCellEditor getCellEditor(int row, int column) {
                int modelColumn = convertColumnIndexToModel(column);
                int modelRow = convertRowIndexToModel(row);
                if (modelColumn == 1 && modelRow == 1) {
                    return myCellEditor;
                } else {
                    return super.getCellEditor(row, column);
                }
            }
        };
        this.add(table);
    }

    private void display() {
        JFrame f = new JFrame("TableTest");
        f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        f.add(this);
        f.pack();
        f.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        f.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                new TableTest().display();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: in fact the table is already in a `JSplitPane`, and is showing proprieties of some `JTree` nodes, when they are highlighted. plain-text display was ok, but not since i added the `CellEditor`, so the table must be in a container already since it's visible.

Comment: Absent your [sscce](http://sscce.org/), I am unable to reproduce the effect you describe; I've elaborated above.

Comment: this is not working, i just added `System.out.println("just for testing");` under `int modelRow = convertRowIndexToModel(row);` line, but nothing is showing up!

Comment: and what you got is just what i want

Comment: ... but cant reach it myself!

Comment: i was debugging the file, and created a preakpoint at the `public TableCellEditor getCellEditor(int row, int column) {` line, but it was never reached. why `getCellEditor()` is being ignored?

Comment: @Man o War my guess (it's a guess only because you are not showing an sscce) is that the table on screen is not the table you added the breakpoint to ...

Answer (score 2):

1) create [JTable](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html), [TableModel](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html#data), [JComboBox](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/combobox.html), then put that together as [example](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html#combobox) from official tutorial

2) for Boolean Component isn't required create own [TableCellEditor](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html#editor), JTable by default
supporting String, Integer, Double, Boolean, Date and [Icon/ImageIcont](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/icon.html) in the TableCell

another examples for a.m.... [here](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/Swing-JFC/CatalogSwing-JFC.htm), [here](http://www.exampledepot.com/egs/javax.swing.table/pkg.html) from this forum [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7183503/how-would-i-go-about-changing-the-boolean-string-to-a-jcheckbox-in-jtable/7183748#7183748), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6946205/how-to-get-values-of-other-cell-if-checkbox-is-selected-of-the-correcponding-chec/6948744#6948744), and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7132400/jtable-row-hightlighter-based-on-value-from-tablecell)

Comment: in all those examples, the editor is set for the whole __column__, but in my case, i want to change the editor to a `jComboBox` only for some __cells__

Comment: "I want to change the editor to a `JComboBox` only for _some_ cells." You can use the `row` parameter to decide what component to return.

Comment: @trashgod: this is exactly what i did; i specified both row and column, but nothing is happening, and table is always blank!